# Can't SSH into Ubuntu Server VM on Mac host

Tags: server, virtualbox, ssh

I have a Mac running Sierra and an Ubuntu Server VM. I am trying to SSH into it but I get this error: `ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: Operation timed out`

At first I was getting a different error but I changed `Port 22` to `Port 2222` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and now I get the error above. The server is running.

The command that I used on the Mac was this: `sudo ssh WR-Server@10.0.2.15` and my VirtualBox connection is set to bridged

Comment: Ensure you are using a bridged or host-only adaptor type in your virtualbox configuration; not NAT.

Comment: I am using bridged

Comment: So your mac also has a 10.0.2.x address?  That address range is typically used by virtualbox for NAT connections.

Comment: My Mac has 10.0.0.7

Comment: And the subnet masks on each device match, and are 22 or lower?  Why are you running `sshd` on port 2222 but attempting to connect on port 22 ?

Comment: I was getting a different error before and looked up an answer and it said to change it from port 22 to port 2222

Comment: You need to use the same port on both client and server.  Either change the server config back to port 22, or use 2222 on the client: 'ssh -p2222 WR-Server@${IP_ADDR}`

Comment: I changed it back and I get the same error

Comment: Please update your question to include the text of both errors you receive (you give one, but not "a different error"), and in which cases you get them.  Add the address and routing configuration for each machine: ubuntu `ip -4 a` and `ip -4 r`.   Mac `ifconfig ${interface name}` and `netstat -f inet -rn`.

Comment: No. I'll just get a web server online. Thanks for nothing.

Comment: @JordanBaron Is that port open in to the Ubutu's firewall?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to ensure that the firewall was turned off on the VM before proceeding with the network adapter changes.  Some O/S versions default with the firewall turned on which may block incoming SSH connection attempts.  After turning off iptables or ufw depending on your O/S version or whichever service you are using.  IF this doesn't resolve the issue, then try each network adapter setting within VirtualBox.

```
sudo ufw disable
```

or

```
sudo service iptables stop
```